# Protractor: Error: Spec patterns did not match any files

Tags: automated-tests, protractor

I have a problem of

```
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: Spec patterns did not match any files.
```

when i try to start my test..

I've got a file config:

```
exports.config = {
    framework : "jasmine",
    params : {
        url : {...},
        txt : {...},
        specs : [
            "../test/settings_changePass.js"
        ]
    }
};
```

Also have a Require file:

```
var elements = { ... };
module.exports = elements;
```

And my test file:

```
describe('test setting', function() {
var elements = require('./elements_settings');
...
});
```

What can be the problem with? 
I have the same structure of these files in other folder and it works well there..

Comment: why you use `selenium` tag for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry! The question is solved. It was just my inattention with One Scope!

```
exports.config = {
framework : "jasmine",
params : {
    url : {...},
    txt : {...},
},
    specs : [
        "../test/settings_changePass.js"
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that you dont have a specification file with the name "settings_changePass.js at the directory address:

```
"../test/settings_changePass.js"
```

By default, protractor locates specifications starting from the project root directory. For example:

```
ProtractorProject/specs/settings_changePass.js
```

can be found in your config file by:

```
specs: ["specs/settings_changePass.js"]
```

Comment: the full root of my spec file is: file:/Users/User/Work/e2e/settings/test/settings_changePass.js.

i have the same, but working spec file in other folder, with root: file:/Users/User/Work/e2e/posting/test/1_user_s_phone.js. and in that config file it looks like: "../test/1_user_s_phone.js"

Comment: i want to add that it works good before i made an Require file. i will try to delete my Require file to see what happens. but..